# How to Style Material UI Select Popup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I have the following react select component working correctly except I'd like different background colors and fonts for the select options.

[image]

**Select Code**

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  select
  size="small"
  name="trigger"
  value={thisTrigger}
  onChange={(selectedOption) => {
    doSetTrigger(selectedOption);
  }}
  InputProps={{disableUnderline: true}}
>
  {triggers.map((trigger, index) => (
    <MenuItem
      key={index}
      value={index}
    >
      {trigger.ENDPOINT}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

and I've tried every which way I can think of to style it - this was my latest attempt

```
root: {
    'background': 'linear-gradient(#F0F0FA, #F0F0FA)',
    'height': '100vh',
    'width': '100%',
    'position': 'relative',
    '& .MuiList-padding': {
      'borderRadius': '10px',
      'background': 'white',
      'color': '#001C32',
      'fontWeight': 400,
      'fontFamily': '"Manrope", "Roboto", "Arial", "sans-serif"',
      'lineHeight': '1.5',
      'fontSize': '1em',
    },
  },
```

Which surprised me when it didn't work, because I can add a background color to `.MuiList-padding` in the browser dev tools, and it works!

I must be missing something; any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: can you provide the full example in code sandbox

Comment: why you are using TextField for Select?

Comment: If you read https://material-ui.com/components/selects/, it specifically mentions using a _TextField_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *MenuProps* suggestion from @Nisharg didn't *quite* work for me, unfortunately. It came *oh so close*, though. And it gave me enough to find a solution. Below is what worked for me:

```
                  <TextField
                    fullWidth
                    select
                    size="small"
                    name="trigger"
                    value={thisTrigger}
                    onChange={(selectedOption) => {
                      doSetTrigger(selectedOption);
                    }}
                    InputProps={{disableUnderline: true}}
                    SelectProps={{
                      MenuProps: {
                        classes: {paper: classes.cmdSelect},
                      },
                    }}
                  >
                    {triggers.map((trigger, index) => (
                      <MenuItem
                        key={index}
                        value={index}
                      >
                        {trigger.ENDPOINT}
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                  </TextField>
```

Where `classes.cmdSelect` looks like this:

```
  cmdSelect: {
    '& ul': {
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    },
  },
```

**Boom!**

Comment: I am happy that you found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this

```
MenuProps={{ classes: { list: classes.menu } }}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-kare-c815b?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Didn't work for me - but it got me _oh so close_ and gave me ideas. Thanks!